# How to use p5 SVG in a web app with React frontend and an Express backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, svg, p5.js

I have a code in p5.js that uses SVG canvas based on https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg library. I have a React frontend that is supposed to draw the contents of the p5.js script. The problem that has arised now is that React has wrappers for the standard p5 library like `react-p5-wrapper`, `react-use-p5` or `p5`; but they don't cover SVG. So the questions would be:

- How to run p5.js SVG code on a React frontend (can we bypass React?)
- Otherwise, how to run the p5.js SVG code on a headless browser on the Express backend and later return the results to the frontend.

p5.js SVG sample code:

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 200, SVG);  
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    fill('#ED225D');
    noStroke(); 
    ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the running p5.js in your Express backend, I haven't tested p5.svg, but see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67434089/229247

Comment: For the record I got the backend rendering working. Here's a demo: https://replit.com/@KumuPaul/Javascript-NodeP5#index.js
To make this work, in addition to the js-dom/window packages I had to use and get setup to make p5.js happy, I had to pull in the `@thednp/dommatrix` package to provide an implementation of DOMMatrix, and I had to write my own (possibly buggy) DOMPoint implementation using `js-matrix`. Fun times 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on exactly which p5.js wrapper you are using in your React app, but fundamentally `p5.js-svg` should work just fine. One issue you might run into is getting `p5.js-svg` to properly initialize in a context were p5 is not being exported globally (i.e. the wrapper is importing the `p5` type via `require()` or `import`). To account for this you may have to do some extra work to initialize `p5.js-svg` before you call `createCanvas` (the default export from `p5.js-svg` is an initialization function that expects to be called with the `p5` type as its argument). However, given that this works fine with [`react-p5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5) I think you need to include a minimal reproducible example using the specific p5.js wrapper you are using.

Here is an example of a component using `react-p5` that renders as an SVG:

```
import React from 'react';
import Sketch from 'react-p5';
// import p5 from 'p5';

// even though this import isn't used it is necessary because the p5.js-svg
// module auto-initializes so long as p5 is defined on window
import p5svg from 'p5.js-svg';

// Initialize p5.js-svg
// This isn't necessary because react-p5 exports the p5 type via window.p5
// p5svg(p5);

let x = 50;
let y = 50;

export default (props) => {
    const setup = (p, canvasParentRef) => {
        // use parent to render the canvas in this ref
        // (without that p5 will render the canvas outside of your component)
        p.createCanvas(500, 500, p.SVG).parent(canvasParentRef);
    };

    const draw = (p) => {
        p.background(0);
        p.fill(props.color || 'blue');
        p.ellipse(x % p.width, y, 70, 70);
        // NOTE: Do not use setState in the draw function or in functions that are executed
        // in the draw function...
        // please use normal variables or class properties for these purposes
        x++;
    };

    return <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} />;
};
```

*Note: it's very inefficient to render animations like the one using `p5.js-svg`. Because of the nature of p5.js, which draws content in immediate mode, there is a lot of risk of creating a memory leak rendering animations as an SVG (if you don't call `background()` or `clear()`), and even if you do then entire SVG must be redrawn every frame. So hopefully you're using this with `noLoop()` to draw something that doesn't change frequently and or isn't too complex.*