# Exporting/downloading p5.js canvas to SVG

Tags: reactjs, next.js, p5.js

I am having issues trying to implement a button where I can download my p5 canvas, the canvas is drawing as it should bt it saves as a PNG, is it not possible to get as a SVG?

I am using Next.js with typescript.

Setup code:

```
const setup = (p5: p5Types, canvasParentRef: Element) => {
    const canvasWidth = Number(partition.width) / devider;
    const canvasHeight = Number(partition.height) / devider;
    p5.createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasHeight).parent(canvasParentRef);
};
```

Draw code:

```
const draw = (p5: p5Types) => {
    // make a loop that iterates over filteredentries and uses the values to draw rectangles
    p5.background(255);

    for (let i = 0; i < lenghtOfSolution; i++) {
      if (solution?.wid?.[i] == 0) {
        p5.fill(0, 0, 0, 50); // red
        p5.rect(
          solution.x[i] / devider,
          solution.y[i] / devider,
          solution.w[i] / devider,
          solution.h[i] / devider
        );
      } else {
        p5.fill(255, 255, 255); // white
        p5.rect(
          solution.x[i] / devider,
          solution.y[i] / devider,
          solution.w[i] / devider,
          solution.h[i] / devider
        );
      }
      if (solution.w[i] > 50) {
        p5.textSize(10);
        p5.fill(0, 0, 0);
        p5.text(
          `ID:${solution.wid[i]}`,
          (solution.x[i] / devider + solution.x2[i] / devider) / 2,
          (solution.y[i] / devider - 20 + solution.y2[i] / devider) / 2
        ).textAlign(p5.CENTER, p5.CENTER);
        p5.textSize(12);
        p5.text(
          `${solution.w[i]} x ${solution.h[i]}`,
          (solution.x[i] / devider + solution.x2[i] / devider) / 2,
          (solution.y[i] / devider + solution.y2[i] / devider) / 2 + 5
        ).textAlign(p5.CENTER, p5.CENTER);
      }
    }
};
```

Sketch code:

```
return (
    <Sketch
      setup={setup}
      draw={draw}
    />
  );
```

I tried using p5.svg library, but it seems to have some issues with Next.js (SSR), I am currently importing p5 like this

```
const Sketch = dynamic(import('react-p5'), { ssr: false });
```

which works for now, but I get it as PNG, not SVG.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://editor.p5js.org/dannyrozin/sketches/r1djoVow7 and this: https://github.com/zenozeng/p5.js-svg ?

Comment: You are going to need to find a way to use `p5.js-svg`. Normal `p5.js` definitely only supports saving raster files, not SVG, because that is fundamentally how it draws things. You should re-ask your question specifically about the issues you experienced using Next.js SSR w/ p5js-svg. I have previously answered a question about using p5.js outside of the web browser here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67431666/p5-breaks-in-node-js/67434089#67434089 and I have added SVG support to my example. Some of the techniques I used for that may apply in your case.